# std::string — small string optimization and swap

Tags: c++, c++11

From N3290, [container.requirements.general]:

> The expression `a.swap(b)`, for containers a and b of a standard container type other than `array`, shall exchange the values of a and b without invoking any move, copy, or swap operations on the individual container elements.

How do this interact with small string optimization? Did they forget to add `std::string` too?

Comment: I don't think string is a "container" in the sense being used here.

Comment: @Logan: then the question becomes: "is string a container?", and if you can provide a correct citation it will be the answer.

Comment: @ybungalobill : The fact that `basic_string` is not described in the `Containers Library` chapter of the FDIS is a good clue. ;-]

Comment: If they'd left concepts in, we'd know for sure...

Comment: @ildjarn: seems you're right. it makes my question pointless...

Comment: @Logan: specifically, 23.3.1/1 lists "sequence containers" and doesn't mention `basic_string`. 21.4 includes a lot of stuff very similar to container requirements, without AFAIK referring to the container requirements. Quacks like a container, but isn't a container.

Comment: @Steve, @ildjarn: you could post these as answers you know... I don't have anything to accept :(

Comment: Yeah I didn't know chapter and verse which is why I didn't make it an answer.

Comment: @ybungalobill: I thought Logan would, I was just giving him the section numbers...

Comment: @Steve Jessop: Actually, I don't think concepts wouldn't help. std::basic_string has all of the *API* necessary to be an STL container. But it doesn't have the same *semantics* as other standard containers. Concepts could only deal with syntax (API); semantics (outside of an il-conceived and il-specified addendum to the proposal) would not work.

Comment: @Nicol: Concepts have `axioms` which describe semantics. Although it cannot be checked in general by the compiler, it still could be used to unambiguously define what's a container and what's not.

Comment: @ybungalobill: Correction: a version of the concepts proposal had axioms. While Stroustrup was a big proponent of them, there were plenty of people on the committee who were against the idea of having syntax that had no actual meaning to the compiler. It's unknown whether it would have passed with axioms, and I'd bet money that the next version of concepts we get won't have them in it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

(Reposting from comment)

`std::string` is not a container – the fact that `basic_string` is not described in the `Containers library` chapter (§23) of the FDIS is a good clue. ;-]

Comment: Yay! now I know yet another difference between `vector<char>` and `string`!

Comment: 21.4 **used to** claim that basic_string was a container, but that was obviously removed for the FDIS.

Comment: @Bo: yeah, seems you're right too. But it's 21.3 in the old standard, C++98: "basic_string conforms to the the requirements of a Reversible Container".