# C++11 and C++03 differs in support for small string optimization for std::string?

Tags: c++, string, c++11, language-lawyer

In the compatibility appendix of the C++11 standard, one of the change from C++03 to C++11 is described as below:

> **C.2.11  Clause 21: strings library**
>   **21.4.1**
>   **Change**: Loosen basic_string invalidation rules
>   **Rationale**: Allow small-string optimization.
>   **Effect on original feature**: Valid C++ 2003 code may execute
>   differently in this International Standard.  Some const member
>   functions, such as data and c_str, no longer invalidate iterators.

The iterator invalidation rule of `std::string` does have changed from C++03 to C++11 in that `data()` and `c_str()` is not allowed to invalidate iterators anymore, but I don't know how that leads to the rationale of "`allow small-string optimization`"?  Wasn't SSO already allowed prior to C++11?

---

Two of the differences of `std::string` between C++11 and C++03 that I knew of before I came across that SSO notes in the compatibility appendix are:

- Elements are guaranteed to be stored contiguously in C++11
- COW implementation is not an option in C++11 (certain operations such as `operator[]` is not allowed to invalidate iterators)

I took C++11's non-invalidating guarantee of `c_str()` and `data()` as the direct result of the change towards contiguous storage.  Now it seems there is some connection with SSO implementation, and I would like to know the detail of the behind-scene logic.  Thanks.

Comment: Are elements not guarantied to be stored contiguously in c++03?

Comment: I don't see such guarantee in C++03.

Comment: c++03 did not require contiguous string; it could be stored in multiple blocks. Also, the string buffer (if there was even a single one) did not have to be null-terminated; the `c_str()` function could point to a completely separate location to `&s[0]` that was just created when `c_str()` was called.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you are misinterpreting the "Change": this is not referring to the invalidation rules of `data` and `c_str`, but rather those of `swap`.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390756/stdstring-small-string-optimization-and-swap) gave me this idea, and I think I am correct when I read your quote and the linked question/answers.

Since `basic_string`'s swap can invalidate iterators, one can implement a SSO. In C++03, `basic_string` was a reversible container, which means it had to comply with this requirement for `swap`ping containers:

> The expression a.swap(b), for containers a and b of a standard container type other than array, shall exchange the values of a and b without invoking any move, copy, or swap operations on the individual container elements.

I may be immensely wrong though, IANALL (I am not a language lawyer).

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the redirection.  So the real difference affecting the possibility of SSO implementation is that C++03's `std::string` is  a reversible container while C++11's `std::string` is not even a container, is this right?  So it's actually true that SSO is not an option prior to C++11?  Thanks again.

Comment: @goodbyeera Yes, that's how I understand this. But `std::string` not being a container does not mean it can't be used as one for most cases. In fact, this `swap` business is the only thing I came across that actually makes it different. `std::string`'s interface was even extended to more closely resemble `std::vector` in C++11. It's a fine line between possible optimizations, semantics, and interface that's being shifted slightly here.