# Extract the generic type of another generic type in C++

Tags: c++, templates, generics

Say I have a class Foo which uses two different generic types, one is `_Type` and the other is `_Comparator`.  `_Type` is known to be a `std::vector`, `std::list`, or `std::string`, so it will have a type within it: `T` will be within `vector` and `list`; `char` will be within `string`.

My other generic type `_Comparator` is an optional template parameter, by which the user may specify her own less than function, functor, or lambda function.  If no argument is provided as the second template parameter, it should default to the `std::less<M>` functor, whereby type `M` shall be the type of elements contained within `_Type`.

I do not know the syntax for how to do this.

I've tried:

```
template <typename _Type<T>, typename _Comparator = less<T> >
```

to no avail.

Comment: Please note that your names are invalid: names starting with underscore followed by an uppercase letter are reserved for the implementation, you may not use them yourself in code.

Comment: All container types have a `value_type` typedef inside them. So if you're certain that `Type` will always be a container you can use `Type::value_type` to access the contained type. And yes, `std::string` is a container to, a very specialized one.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I'm a bit confused:  reserved for which implementation?  Also, the names of the template arguments were given with a homework assignment, so I think they should be valid for the purpose, or I'm misunderstanding you here.

Comment: The compiler implementation. And if your teacher gave you those names you should tell the teacher to stop.

Comment: Noted. I'll raise the point with him.

Comment: Joachim Pileborg's comment is probably what you want, but for completeness, in situations where the container isn't nice enough to give you a typedef for its inner type, you can dig it out with decltype (requires C++11).

Comment: Isn't this about template template parameters?

Comment: @jsantander what OP is asking for can be easily done without them.

Comment: @Joachim `std::string` does not fullfil all requirements to be a container. See e.g. my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22323637/256138), which refers to the more explicit answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6390927/256138). Nonetheless, for what is required in this context, you are right that it provides the usual typedefs, but those do not make it a `C++ container (tm)`.

Comment: @Joachim: and those names are reserved for both C++ Standard Library and Compiler implementors. They aren't required to be the same (see e.g. Clang using GCC's libstdc++).

Answer (score 2):

Using the approach mentioned by @Joachim Pileborg in the comments, I was able to come up with the following, which allowed me to access the inner type of `_Type`:

```
template <typename _Type, 
    typename _Comparator = less<typename _Type:: value_type> >
class Foo
{
    public:
        // some methods
    private:
        _Type sequence;
        _Comparator comparator;
};
```

and now `std::less` compares the correct types without complaining.

Answer (score 0):

if I understood your question correctly, you might try something like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <typeinfo>

template <typename T>
class holder
{
public:
    template <typename Type = std::vector<T>, typename Comparator = std::less<T> >
    class impl
    {
    public:
        impl() {std::cout << typeid(s).name() << std::endl; }
        Type s;
    };

} ;

int main()
{
    holder<int>::impl<> holder_of_int_vectors;
    holder<int>::impl<std::list<int> > holder_of_int_lists;
    holder<int>::impl<std::list<int>, std::greater<int> > holder_of_int_lists_with_greater;
}
```

ie, use an external class to hold the "basic" type (`T`) and an internal for the container (`Type`) and comparator.

Comment: `Type` does not have a default template parameter though, such as `std::vector`.

Comment: That's ok, just remove it, and in this case also you will need to specify it explicitly for `holder_of_int_vectors` to be: `holder<int>::impl<std::vector<int> >  `

Answer (score 0):

As you said you only want to support `vector`, `list`, and `string`, you can use this:

```
template <typename T, typename Compare = std::less<typename T::value_type>>
```

This will support all types which have a member typedef `value_type`, which `vector`, `list`, and `string` all do.

It's possible to support other types using variadic template template parameters, but that's getting much more complicated.

Comment: Yep, this is what I ended up using.  See the below answer.  I think it wins with simplicity, since I don't need comprehensive support.